# Необходимо получить вложенный элемент в массиве json

Tags: ajax, typescript, angular

Есть некоторый список элементов в формате json, выглядит следующим образом:

```
[{'id':0,"name":"Имя категории1","services":[{"id":0,"name":"Имя товара1"},{"id":1,"name":"Имя товара2"}]},
{'id':1, 'name':"Имя категории2", "services":[{"id":0,"name":"Имя товара1"},{"id":1,"name":"Имя товара2"}]}
]
```

Я пытаюсь получить только из первой категории весь массив "services".
Условно я пытаюсь его получить следующим образом:

```
this.class = this.http.get('/assets/products.json');
this.class.forEach(element =>{
if(element.id==ID) //ID получается при вызове функции, в которой выполняется этот код
{
console.log(element.services);
}})
```

Однако мне это даёт абсолютным счётом ничего и в консоль выводится "undefined", однако при таком же массиве и в таких же условиях на сайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach он (foreach и console.log) выводит всё то, что мне нужно.

```
//Такой же foreach только на сайте мозиллы
array1.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id==1){ //1 вместо ID
    console.log(item.services);
  }});
```

Вывод в консоль: Array [Object { id: 0, name: "Имя товара1"}, Object { id: 1, name: "Имя товара2"}].
P.S.
Мне на самом деле не нужен этот список товаров в консоли, я пытаюсь передать переменной, но поскольку в переменную, как и в консоль, передаётся undefined, я не могу пользоваться переменной и вызывать её, чтобы отображать товары на странице. Всё это используется в typescript angular проекте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this.http.get<any[]>('/assets/products.json').subscribe((data) => { 
> this.class = data; 
> this.class.forEach((element) => { 
> if (element.id == ID) { 
> console.log(element.services);
> }
> });
> });
> ответ дал Octavian Mărculescu с англоязычного stackoverflow, за что ему большое спасибо. Так же была ошибка в присвоении ID в ngOnInit, а не в конструкторе (я не знал, что конструктор срабатывает раньше ngOnInit)

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедись, что this.http.get('/assets/products.json'); возвращает необходимые данные.
2. Убедись, что данные от this.http.get('/assets/products.json') присвоились переменной class.
   Если пункты нормально работают, то и forEach должен работать исправно. undefined - значит, что в переменной ничего нет, а это, скорей всего, значит, что метод get не вернул ничего.

Comment: Я задал аналогичный вопрос на аглоязычный stackoverflow, можешь глянуть. Но изложу суть в нескольких предложениях: ...http.get... возвращает нужные мне данные и они присваиваются переменной class, так же ID спокойно воспринимается конструкцией "if" из-за чего и происходит вывод в консоль. Однако ID тоже undefined, и соотвественно вопрос если undefined - ничего, то почему "if" его воспринимает, если должен сразу выходить из конструкции ничего не выводя? Если что он (console.log) не выводит element.id/.name/.services, но спокойно может выводить весь массив element, все категории и товары